# VBS script 'Path not found' error when setting file system folder object reference

Tags: vbscript, path

I am writing a script to determine the combined size  of all instances of a particular subfolder within the profile folder of each user who has logged onto a Windows 2003 server, e.g. all users' desktop folders or all users' local settings folders.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim colSubfolders, intCount, intCombinedSize, objFolder2, objFSO1, objFSO2, objUserFolder, strOutput, objSearchFolder, objSubfolder, strSearchFolder, strSubfolderPath

intCount = 0
intCombinedSize = 0
strSearchFolder = "C:\Documents and Settings\"

Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSearchFolder = objFSO1.GetFolder(strSearchFolder)
Set colSubfolders = objSearchFolder.SubFolders

For Each objUserFolder in colSubfolders
  strSubfolderPath = objUserFolder.Path & "\Desktop\"
  Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objSubfolder = objFSO2.GetFolder(strSubfolderPath)
  intCount = intCount + 1
  intCombinedSize = intCombinedSize + objSubfolder.Size
Next

MsgBox "Combined size of " & CStr(intCount) & " folders: " & CStr(intCombinedSize / 1048576) & " MB"
```

This code throws a 'Path not found' error (Code 800A004C) at line 15:

```
Set objSubfolder = objFSO2.GetFolder(strSubfolderPath)
```

If I print out strSubfolderPath, however, I find that all the strings returned are valid directory paths, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

I've tried with and without the trailing backslash at the end of the path and I've tried with 8.3 style paths to remove spaces but to no effect.

Comment: Does the account you run the script under has permissions to access these folders and view their size in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Curious: why are you creating more than one `FileSystemObject` instead of just reusing the same one?

Comment: Didn't realise I didn't need to create another `FileSystemObject` as I'm still new to VBS. Thanks @Jean-François Corbett for pointing that out.

Comment: @Helen I forgot to include in the original question that the script is running as an administrator account with access to all the directories, but thanks for checking. Question solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get the same error.

Upon further inspection, on my computer there is a folder named `C:\Documents and Settings\machinename`, where *machinename* is the name of my computer. This folder only contains one subfolder named `ASPNet`.

I'm guessing you have something similar.

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't spotted the hidden folders LocalService and NetworkService, which are Desktop-less. I added `If objFSO.FolderExists(strSubfolderPath) Then` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize multiple-backslash confusion, use the `FileSystemObject` methods consistently instead of relying on string concatenation:

```
strSubfolderPath = objFSO1.BuildPath(objUserFolder.Path,"Desktop")
```